# Why do I get "error: invalid channel name '[toolchain]'" for a dependency when it is in the simple format?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

When I try to add sfw-tools v0.2.0 to a project, I run into this issue:

```
   Compiling sfw-tools v0.2.0
error: invalid channel name '[toolchain]' in '/home/brandon/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/sfw-tools-0.2.0/rust-toolchain'
error: caused by: invalid toolchain name: '[toolchain]'
error: could not compile `sfw-tools`
```

Perplexingly, in the `SoftwareTools` repository, the contents of the `rust-toolchain` file is just

```
nightly-2020-12-25-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
```

(though it is a symbolic link).

Note: I'm guilty of being the author of the dependency as well, so on the bright side, I can probably fix it, once I understand the issue.

Answer (score 0):

`ripgrep` to the rescue:

```
$ rg "\[toolchain\]"
Rust/sfw-tools/rust-toolchain
1:[toolchain]


ls -last rust-toolchain
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 brandon users 36 Dec 26 20:43 rust-toolchain -> Rust/sfw-tools/rust-toolchain.simple
```

Oops.

So, I needed to rename `Rust/sfw-tools/rust-toolchain.simple` to be the actual toolchain file